# How to make figure changes survive the Reset button in bokeh

Tags: bokeh

I am dynamically changing figure properties in bokeh, and am finding that pressing the Reset button in the toolbar reverts changes that I've made in code. An example (run with `bokeh serve`):

```
import bokeh.plotting
import bokeh.models
import bokeh.layouts
import numpy as np

# set up the interface
fig = bokeh.plotting.figure(x_range=(0, 10), y_range=(0, 10))
plt = fig.line(np.linspace(0, 10, 20), np.random.random(20) * 10)
button = bokeh.models.Button(label='scramble')

# add everything to the document
bokeh.plotting.curdoc().add_root(bokeh.layouts.column(button, fig))

# define a callback and connect it
def callback():
    fig.y_range.start, fig.y_range.end = [0, 20]
button.on_click(callback)
```

What happens here is that the plot is first displayed with y range (0, 10). When I press my `Button` widget, the y range is changed to (0, 20) as specified. But if I then press the toolbar's Reset button, the y range goes back to (0, 10). Is this the indended behavior?

What if I want to make changes in the code that describe the state after a potential Reset? This feels like a natural feature, dynamically providing a reasonable state of a plot in a callback, allowing the user to zoom and pan around and then get back to that reasonable state using the Reset button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is the intended behavior. The express purpose of the built-in `ResetTool` is to reset the plot to its *original state*. If you want to reset to some different state, you could write your own custom tool as a Bokeh extension, or you could just have a "reset button" with a callback instead of the standard `ResetTool`. It sounds like you actually have the latter already? If so perhaps what you want is to just remove the `ResetTool` from the list of tools on the plot in the first place, and only show your "custom reset" button to users.

Comment: to address the scenario Alex describes at the end of his question is there any way to update the values that the reset button reverts to? I'm trying to avoid either having a separate button outside the toolbar or implementing a custom tool in TypeScript.

Comment: There is not currently any capability to manually set the reset state.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what happens here is that you initialise the document in python and then the bokeh js and python part are not sychronized once rendered in the browser. But the bokeh server supports that kind of sychronization [documentation](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#connecting-with-bokeh-client)

```
# open a session to keep our local document in sync with server
session = push_session(curdoc())
```

Comment: Thanks, but even with the example to which you link, if you set one y_range in the `figure()` call and then change it in the callback `update()` function, pressing Reset reverts to the y_range specified upon figure creation. You have to slow down the periodic callback to see this of course.